# Generated Javadoc is different from what NetBeans popup shows

Tags: java, netbeans, javadoc

I'm using NetBeans and have the following code:

```
   public interface StackADT<E> extends Collection<E> {
        boolean push(E element);
        E pop();
        E peek();
   }

   public class ArrayStack<E> implements StackADT<E> {
       //other methods

       /** Adds all the elements of a given collection to
        *  the stack.
        * @param c the collection whose elements should be
        *          added.
        * @return <br>{@code true} if the collection does not
        *         contain {@code null} elements.
        */
       @Override
       public boolean addAll(Collection<? extends E> c) {
           //do stuff
       }
   }
```

When I generate the Javadoc for the project, it correctly shows
[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0w7yO.png). However, the documentation popup shows [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Im3KP.png). For some reason, the `return` tag shows text from `Collections`' documentation that's supposed to be overriden, but only in the popup. I've tried restarting NetBeans and rewriting the method's Javadoc to no effect. Any ideas?

Comment: It's... unusual to override a method and change what it's return type means.  Which is likely why NetBeans is pulling the `@return` from `java.util.Collection<E>` as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a bug. I created an [issue](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NETBEANS-4070) and [PR](https://github.com/apache/netbeans/pull/2047) for that. I think it will be fixed in 12.1.

You can check it easily. If you change your JavaDoc like this (move the return tag to the top):

```
   /** Adds all the elements of a given collection to
    *  the stack.
    * @return <br>{@code true} if the collection does not
    *         contain {@code null} elements.
    *
    * @param c the collection whose elements should be
    *          added.
    */
```

then the description of the param tag would be duplicated instead of the return tag:

[image]